# DTLS-DTLS is not enabled

Tags: webrtc, sipml

I built the source of webrtc2sip, when i run it i got messages:

```
SSL is enabled :)
DTLS supported: yes
DTLS-SRTP supported: yes
```

Page with sipML5 connects without errors with websocket to my webrtc2sip gateway. In SIPml.Stack i'm using option: websocket_proxy_url with address:

```
ws://192.168.1.102:10060
```

But when i send an invite (audio call) i'm getting this error:

```
***[DOUBANGO ERROR]: function: "tdav_session_av_set_ro()" 
file: "/Users/kamil/doubango/tinyDAV/src/tdav_session_av.c" 
line: "1416" 
MSG: Remote party requesting DTLS-DTLS (UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF) but this option is not enabled
```

Can it be a problem with certificates ? or maybe with openssl (1.0.2g) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using SSL, the correct websocket_proxy_url should be:

```
wss://{SSL Domain}:{WSS Port}
```

Where:

```
{SSL Domain} is your Fully Qualified Domain Name associated with your SSL key
```

and

```
{WSS Port} is the wss port you have configured in the webrtc2sip config.xml file
```